# Eclipse RCP adding External Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a plug-in from jar files. I have added the this plugin in dependencies plugin.xml and also in target. When I try to run the rcp application from eclipse it is working fine. Then I exported the product with the Eclipse product Export Wizard. When I tried to open the eclipse.exe it is giving me error

**An error has occured. Seee log file xxxxxxxxxxx.log**

The log file contains

```
!SESSION 2011-09-15 02:16:13.343 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-15 02:16:15.189
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in in.expertsoftware.tdesk was unable to load class in.expertsoftware.tdesk.Application.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in.expertsoftware.tdesk.Application
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    ... 16 more
```

what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With some observation of MANIFEST.MF, I found **jars.compile.order** attribute. Which is actually causing the problem. After removing this which is actually not necessary it works fine as a product too.